# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str Pytest with Moto DynamoDB

Tags: python, pytest, moto

I am new to Python and this error seems to be to a general one and I can't understand it the context of my case.
I am trying to unit test a class that is used to connect to DynamoDB with [Pytest.](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/)
and [Moto mocks.](https://github.com/spulec/moto)
Test:

```
@mock_dynamodb
def test_save_alarm_configs_in_db(apigw_event):
    repo = DynamoDBRepository()
    client = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')
    create_table_response = client.create_table(
        AttributeDefinitions=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'frequency',
                'AttributeType': 'N'
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'time_period',
                'AttributeType': 'S'
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'destinations',
                'AttributeType': 'M'
            }
        ],
        TableName='alarm_configs',
        KeySchema=[
            {
                'AttributeName': "id",
                'KeyType': "HASH"
            }
        ]
    )

    alarm_configs = {
        "id": "123",
        "frequency": 2,
        "time_period": "hour",
        "destinations": [
            {"type": "SNS",
             "properties":
                 [{"topics": ["email_topic"]}]
             }
        ]
    }

    if create_table_response:
        put_response = client.put_item(TableName='alarm_configs', Item=alarm_configs)
        print("Put response:")
        print(put_response)
        expected_item = repo.get_alarm_configs_by_id("123")
        print(expected_item)
```

Error:
https://gist.github.com/AdelinGhanaem/047d4bb32724432350b73f5917daccc7

Comment: Your `KeySchema` is a list containing a single dictionary but should probably just be a dictionary, without the surrounding list. It also seems to be missing a 'HashKeyElement' key. And I shouldn't need to say this to a 16k rep user, but please do some research before asking a question; the error message in the title is very clear and should lead to countless google hits telling you exactly why such an error is thrown.

Comment: The error is misleading @l4mpi - his KeySchema is correct. See my reply below.

Comment: @BertBlommers i would assume that's because of the change to `mock_dynamodb2` from your answer which seems to use a different config format. My proposed fix was based on the code snippet that can be seen in the error messsage, it's a moot point if that decorator should no longer be used anyways. That supports my impression that OP did insufficient research however.

Comment: Boto3 decides the KeySchema-format, so that config does not change. Moto simply parses whatever comes through from Boto3. If anything, this could be classified as a bug in Moto, as it does not detect that boto3 is used.

Comment: My initial reaction was the same, FWIW, but think more research would not have pointed OP anywhere in the right direction. Moto's documentation would not have helped here at all (and that's coming from me, a Moto maintainer..)

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues with your code - some related to Moto, some to boto3.

- When using `boto3`, you should use `@mock_dynamodb2`. `mock_dynamodb` is considered deprecated.

(Edit: See http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/services/dynamodb.html and https://github.com/spulec/moto/issues/4526)

Fixing that should at least give you more useful errors.

Next: The `AttributeDefinitions` should specify the key-types - whether the keys are strings, numbers, etc. That means that the `AttributeDefinitions`-parameter should always mirror the `KeySchema`-attribute.
As you only have the `id` key in the `KeySchema`, it should look like:

```
AttributeDefinitions=[{
    'AttributeName': 'id',
    'AttributeType': 'S'
}],
```

Third:
There are two ways of using the `put_item`-method.
One: using the `boto3.client("dynamodb").put_item`-method.
Two: using the `Table.put_item`-method, where `Table` refers to an instance of the `Table`-class that is returned by `boto3.resource("..").create_table`

As you already have created the table using the `boto3.resource("..")`-call, putting an item can be done like this:

```
put_response = create_table_response.put_item(Item=alarm_configs)
```